# Find coefficient of $X^{12}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I need to find coefficient of $X^{12}$ in $({1-2X})^{19}$.

What is the formula to solve it?I only know about

$$\frac{1}{a-X}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{X^r}{a^r}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-aX)^{n}}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty {X^r}{a^r} C(n-1+r,r)$$

Comment: $r  th term= {(-2X)^r} C(n,r) $

Comment: @user2277550 thank you.it would be helpful if i can get the steps in solving it

Comment: @Pradeep What do you mean? $(-2)^{12}\binom{19}{12}$ is the answer. And you're done.

Comment: @Pradeep What you want is the proof of the binomial expansion. Check it out.

Comment: @user26486 i mean , what if the question was $({1-2X})^{-19}$ ?

Comment: Something's not right in your second formula, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the binomial theorem:

$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$

In this case you have $a=1$, $b=-2X$ and $n=19$

Therefore the term which will have $X^{12}$, is the term in which $k=12$, therefore, for this $k$, we have that

$[X^{12}]=\binom{19}{12} 1^{19-12}(-2)^{12}=\binom{19}{12} (-2)^{12}$

Here $[X^{12}]$ is the coefficient of $X^{12}$ in the expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the steps.A small doubt.What to do if $n$ is negative.If the question was like $({1-2X})^{-19}$

Comment: You can't use the binomial theorem in that case, there is no general rule for that. I don't think that if you are working with binomial theorem, they will ask you for an example like that one. However if they do, you can ask, and we will probably be able to help you. (Every problem is different)

Comment: I'd recommend a Taylor expansion of $(1-x)^{-1}$ combined with binomial then as a plausible route for it then.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use the binomial theorem. Since $f(x)=(1-2x)^{19}$ is a polynomial, it is equal to its Taylor series, that is,
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k. $$
It's clear that for $0\leqslant k\leqslant 19$, $$f^{(k)}(x) = (-2)^k(19)_k(1-2x)^{19-k}, $$
where $(n)_k$ denotes the falling factorial: $$(n)_k = n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1). $$
So $f^{(k)}(0) = (-2)^k(19)_k$ as $f^{(k)}=0$ for $k>19$, we have $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{19} \frac{(-2)^k(19)_k}{k!}x^k. $$
It follows that the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is
$$\frac{(-2)^{12}(19)_{12}}{12!}=2^{12}\binom {19}{12}. $$